# Reliable 1tb or larger hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I am in the market for 2-3 new drives, I would like each to be at least 1tb to 2tb in size. 
I have been reading all the reviews on newegg.com for 1tb and larger drives and they all have 1 thing in common. Almost all the ones I read about have complaints of them being DOA or dieing within a few weeks of use. I am hoping to find some drives with this storage range that have a reputation for lasting a long time instead of a short life.

Please help me if you have any experience with these sort of drives? Most the ones I read about were Western Digital brand.

I realize some might complain that this questions answer would be based upon a timeframe, so if a user searches and find this answer a year from now it will be outdated but I would appreciate any help based on the current hard drives available as of April 10th, 2010 on newegg.com

Comment: which size you want (2.5 or 3.5) or anything like NAS ? IMHO, I prefer Seagate as choice.

Comment: Would prefer 3.5" drives for a desktop

Answer (score 1):

For any brand X drive there always seems to be an equal number of users who say

- "[brand X](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=seagate+sux) failed on me and destroyed all my files, I only ever use brand Y"

and those who say

- "I only ever use brand X, [brand Y](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=western+digital+sux) failed on me destroying all my files".

Drives fail, somewhere between you buying them and the time when they become so pitifully small and slow compared to the current models that you pull them apart to get at the [curiously strong magnets they contain](http://www.dansdata.com/magnets.htm).

The take home lesson is: if you haven't saved it in multiple locations you haven't really saved it. If you want reliability, try a [RAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) (RAID 5 or 6 if possible). I work with video and use a 3Tb external SCSI RAID 6 box which comprised 8 500Mb drive units. In the time I've had it a couple of the physical drives have failed. The only symptom is a loud beeping noise to alert me - I remove the dud drive and swap in a new one (without even shutting down) and meanwhile it shuffles my data around to avoid the problem.

Even still, for anything irreplaceable I use an external server that has regular tape backups made, because if an asteroid hits the edit suite even a RAID won't save me, unless it's very large and very strong and I can crawl under it.